# Visual Studio .natvis file, array of class visualization

Tags: visual-studio, natvis

I have classes that basically look like the following and I would like to make then more readable in Visual Debugger:

```
template <typename T, precision P = defaultp>
struct tvec4
{
    T x, y, z, w;
};

template <typename T, precision P = defaultp>
struct tmat4x4
{
    typedef tvec4<T, P> col_type;

private:
    col_type value[4];
};
```

Here is what the natvis file looks like for the vector:

```
<Type Name="glm::tvec4&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{x}, {y}, {z}, {w}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="x">x</Item>
        <Item Name="y">y</Item>
        <Item Name="z">z</Item>
        <Item Name="w">w</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Which work fine. However, for the matrix class, I can't manage to get anything to work.

Try1:

```
<Type Name="glm::tmat4&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{{value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]}, {value[3]}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[0]">value[0]</Item>
        <Item Name="[1]">value[1]</Item>
        <Item Name="[2]">value[2]</Item>
        <Item Name="[3]">value[3]</Item>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Try2:

```
<Type Name="glm::tmat4&lt;*&gt;">
    <DisplayString>{size = {4 x 4}}</DisplayString>
    <Expand>
        <Item Name="[size]">4</Item>
        <Item Name="[capacity]">4</Item>
        <ArrayItems>
            <Size>4</Size>
            <ValuePointer>value</ValuePointer>
        </ArrayItems>
    </Expand>
</Type>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
Christophe

Answer (score 1):

You should try switching the diagnostics on. It is explained here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Writing-type-visualizers-2eae77a2

Create the registry key below:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\Debugger]
   "EnableNatvisDiagnostics"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so I'm assuming you have a solution by now but just in case anyone else has a similar problem it is down to your use of curly braces in the description:

```
<DisplayString>{{value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]}, {value[3]}}</DisplayString>
```

A single brace {} indicates that the contents should be interpreted by the debugger but if you actually want the brace as part of the description then you need to use double braces:

```
{{Text here {variable_name_here}}}
```

So in your case that would make the correct display string:

```
<DisplayString>{{{value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]}, {value[3]}}}</DisplayString>
```